# Rails - how to send some information from one form to other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Firstly, I would like to describe what I am going to do. So, my application is set of tasks (eg. exercises depend on writing computer program) which user it available to send solutions through form and server will have compiled it and return results of process.
My problem is that I have model `Solution` which is presented below:

```
Solution(id: integer, exercise_id: integer, code: string, user_id: integer,
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, language_id: integer)
```

and `exercise_id, user_id, language_id` are foreign keys and postgresql return error that it couldn't be null values... 
The form which I use to send this information looks like below:

```
<fieldset style="add">
  <legend>Send solution</legend>
    <%= form_for [@user, @exercise, @solution], url: exercise_solutions_path, :html => { role: "form" } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Source code" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.text_area :code %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Programming language" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.select(:language_id, available_lang) %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Send", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

Frankly speaking I don't how to include more information such as user.id or exercise.id. Params look like:

```
@_params    

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"abwhTn3KrVneli0pCVccoWHyzlI7cRTFK5Wo7DdYRK+lL4GwZ8jUPqdzn8ZznCHsWTkfDAFS2RP6gTkWuk33iw==", "solution"=>{"code"=>"ds", "language_id"=>"C++"}, "commit"=>"Wyślij", "controller"=>"solutions", "action"=>"create", "exercise_id"=>"1"}
```

SolutionController

```
class SolutionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @solutions = Solution.last(20)
  end

  def new
    @solution = Solution.new
  end

  def create
    @solution = Solution.new(solution_params)
    if @solution.save
      redirect_to @solution
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @solution = Solution.find(params[:id])
    if @solution.update(solution_params)
      redirect_to @solution
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def solution_params
    params.require(:solution).permit(:language_id, :code)
  end

end
```

Edit:

```
<fieldset style="add">
  <legend>Send solution</legend>
    <%= form_for [@user, @exercise, @solution], url: exercise_solutions_path, :html => { role: "form" } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Source code" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.text_area :code %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label "Programming language" %>
        <br>
        <%= f.select(:language_id, available_lang) %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :exercise_id, value: @exercise.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Send", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you please show the controller code that is handling the form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could 1) add `hidden_field`s in your form to set the missing attributes:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.hidden_field :exercise_id, value: @exercise.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Send", :class => "btn btn-default" %>
</div>
```

Make sure to add these attributes to the `solution_params` permitted parameters:

```
def solution_params
  params.require(:solution).permit(:language_id, :code, :exercise_id, :user_id)
end
```

A better idea would be to manually set the `exercise` and `user` in the controller and leave your `solution_params` as is. That way you're not allowing the exercise and user to be set by mass assignment, which could be spoofed.

So instead do 2) in your controller:

```
def create
  @solution = Solution.new(solution_params)
  @solution.exercise_id = params[:exercise_id]
  @solution.user_id = params[:user_id]

  if @solution.save
    redirect_to @solution
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I'm assuming that `:exercise_id` and `:user_id` are in the URL. If not add them as hidden_fields as needed (but this time not on the form object):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
```

Also remember to actually select a `language_id` from the dropdown before you submit the form.

Comment: I have a form like I added above but I got error that User and Exercise instances are nil.

Comment: These need to be set in your controller: `@user = User.find params[:user_id]`