# How to sent :event_id to some other controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controller in my application events and registrations. I want to send event_id of current event to registrations controller after form submission in event show template

```
show.html.erb

<%= form_for @registrations do |f| %>

   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

registrations_controller

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end
```

end

but it gives me following error

```
cannot find event with id =
```

What i think that since event and registrations are not related in any way.So its giving this error.
How to solve this error

Comment: Can you paste in your server log for the POST request when the form submits?

Comment: @NickM didn't got you, since i am new to rails

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551355/rails-how-to-send-some-information-from-one-form-to-other-controller?rq=1) I am looking for something like this

Comment: Funny, I came up with a similar solution. You just need to get @event.id in your form somewhere and use a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about the model associations and also what the @registrations object is, this is the easiest solution:
Add a hidden field to your form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field( :event_id, @event.id ) %>
# assumes @event exists in the show action somewhere
```

and in your controller:

```
def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:registrations][:event_id])
end
```

If your models are associated you can do something like:

```
<%= form_for @event.registrations.new %>
```

but it's hard to say if that will work in your app based on the code provided.